# Write MySQL query to CSV in php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm trying to write the results of a MYSQL query to a CSV and having issues. The query works, and when I run in powershell it prints the perfect CSV data in powershell, but the file is nowhere to be found on my CPU.

How can I physically write to a CSV?

```
$result = $conn2->query(
                   "SELECT firstn
                , lastn
                , extension
                , Recieved
                , RecievedKnown
                , Outbound
                , outboundKnown
                , Missed
                , MissedKnown
                , CallingNumber
                , CalledNumber
                , starttime
                , endtime
                , duration
                , HOLDTIMESECS
                , TERMINATIONREASONCODE

            FROM (
                  SELECT u.firstn
                , u.lastn")
               //Long query, removing unnecessary code
             ); 




            if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
            $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);
            $headers = array();
            while ($fieldinfo = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
                $headers[] = $fieldinfo->name;
            }
            $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
            if ($fp && $result) {
                header('Content-Type: text/csv');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="dailyReportTestPHP.csv"');
                header('Pragma: no-cache');
                header('Expires: 0');
                fputcsv($fp, $headers);
                while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
                    fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
                }
                die;
            }
```

Comment: You have to write the csv to a file, not`$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');`

Comment: you realize that your post contains a syntax error. Syntax highlighting is showing that.

Comment: Sorry guys, issue with my comment in the query. Fixed it now

Comment: You are mixing mysql drivers. Dont do that

Comment: @tadman He's using mysqli, not the obsolete mysql extension, except he mistakenly used `mysql_num_fields`

Comment: You don't need to use `array_values()`, since `MYSQLI_NUM` means it just returns an array of the values.

Comment: `mysql_num_fields` should be `mysqli_num_fields`

Comment: If you're running the program on the command line, you don't use `header()`, that's for HTTP.

Comment: I'm going to be running as a scheduled task so I'll just remove the header block

Comment: Thanks guys, I fixed the typo, removed headers and modified ```$fp``` to a filename and it works now

Comment: @Barmar Good point.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete headers and edit the line to add the path to the file to it:

```
$ fp = fopen ('php: // output', 'w');
```

**For example**:

```
$ fp = fopen ('c:\\folder\\resource.txt', 'w');
```

**FOR HTTP:**

```
if ($result) {
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=dailyReportTestPHP.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    fputcsv($fp, $headers);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }
    fclose($fp);
    die;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to change your script, you need to pipe the output.

Since you are using `powershell` it would look like this

```
php myscript.php | Out-File c:\output.csv
```

if you are on linux or OS X it would look like this

```
php myscript.php > output.csv
```